# How to make unconstrained variables non-negative (as in excel solver) in AMPL?

Tags: cplex, solver, binary-variable, simplex, ampl

This is a sequencing problem.

I've got this variables

```
var z0{i in jobs} binary;
var z{i in jobs, j in jobs : i <> j} binary;
var w{i in jobs, j in jobs : i <> j};
var o{i in jobs};
```

i and j come from the same set, so z0i is 1 if it's the first job in the sequence, 0 otherwise. zij is 1 if j is after i, 0 otherwise.

I want to calculate w and o with this:

```
subject to rnueve {i in jobs, j in jobs : i <> j}: (x[j]-f[i]) - 10000 * (1 - z[i,j]) = w[i,j];


subject to rdiez {i in jobs}: x[i] - 10000 * (1 - z0[i]) = o[i];
```

The thing is, I need to put the M in from of it so when j is not after i, the variables o and w are super negative.

After that, I need to make those negative values equal to zero, but I don't know how without having to make the solution nonlinear.

In excel's solver, there's a button that does this. You mark: Make unconstrained variables non-negative. And this does what I described.

If I try to make w and o >= 0 I get an infeasible solution because, with the big M, there is no possible way to find a solution with w and o being non negative.

What i want to do is get a negative value, and then if it's actually negative, make it zero.

Comment: Big-M constraints are usually (always?) inequalities.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do here. In AMPL you're normally solving for all model variables simultaneously; "get a negative value and then make it zero" isn't how it usually works.

Comment: Let's focus on constraint rdiez, since it is simpler. x[i] does not appear in the list of variables, so I guess it is a parameter (some data). Are you trying to say the when z0[i] = 1, then o[i] = x[i]; and when z0[i] = 0, then o[i] = 0? That could be expressed as o[i] = x[i] * z0[i]. But if you have something else in mind, how would it be different from this?